# How to stop makefile commands from sourcing my .cshrc.local

Tags: shell, makefile, tcsh

I knew that commands in a makefile get executed in a new instance of shell (one new instance per each command). But I did not know that my .cshrc.local (in case of csh/tcsh) is sourced again for each of that shell instance!

How can I tell make to not do that? I want each shell instance created from inside make to simply get the current shell's environment (the one from where I am running make) and not source my .cshrc.local

Hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I ignored the fact that my command was a shell script (with a shebang /bin/tcsh). I looked at tcsh help, and found that I should pass -f argument if I want to skip sourcing the startup file. Added that to my shell script and it does what I want.

So, I was mistaken that make commands source startup file while creating a new shell instance. They do not.